# Signal Compression Technique

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, signals, signal-processing

I have signal of length 26,000. This signal is collected from a machine sensor. In a very easy way, we can tell that, we attached the sensor to the machine, and then we have collected only 1 second signal from it. That 1 second signal length is 26,000. That means the sampling frequency is 26,000 Hz.

My question is, now if I want to use this signal for my deep learning based algorithms.. suppose CNN and others, this size is very large. (We have collected lots of signals, so it is not that we are passing only one signal to the deep network). How to reduce the size of the signal or how can we compress the signal without loosing much information.

So If I have a huge size signal, and I want to compress it in smaller size, is there any technique that can be suggested?

TIA

Comment: arent there machine learning techniques for this? like PCA and variational autoencoders?

Comment: Actually, from feature space if we want to reduce that is fine. Suppose, we extract 100 features from the data, and then we are applying the PCA/AE. Fine as if we reproduce it, good to go. However, my point is apart from that, is there any compression techniques that can be suggested? BTW, thanks a lot for the suggestion

Comment: Any kind of compression is going to rely on statistical knowledge of the signal, and/or deep understanding of what parts of the signal are significant.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction

I would suggest you take a look at PCA and variational autoencoders. Im not sure what kind of data it is and what dimensions it has though so I cant really be of much help here.

Comment: Actually, from feature space if we want to reduce that is fine. Suppose, we extract 100 features from the data, and then we are applying the PCA/AE. Fine as if we reproduce it, good to go. However, my point is apart from that, is there any compression techniques that can be suggested? BTW, thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Comment: it really depends on what kind of data you have.

Comment: Use zpaq or paq8 for maximal datacompression